# The most 'cake' way to have queries from multiple models on one page?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Within my index page I plan to have data from more than one model. For example, a list of users from the users model, and a list of recent updates from a posts model in two separate areas of the page. How would I go about doing this in the best way possible? From doing a little research it seems that maybe elements are what I'm looking for, but I'm unsure.

I'm using cake 2, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, just use `$this->loadModel('MyModel'); and you'll have access to any/all models you'd like for your index page.

---

OR

The long answer, on how to set up a "homepage" which accesses lots of models:

You can make a DashboardsController (or whatever you want to call it), then in the Dashboard model, you specify that you don't need a database table: `var $useTable = false;`

In the Config/routes.php file, add: `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index'));` to make that your homepage (if you want to).

Then, in the Dashboard controller's index action, you can use `$this->loadModel('Whatever');`, and you're good to go to get data from that model:  `$myData = $this->Whatever->find('all');`. You can load as many models as you'll need the data for.

**TLDR / simplified:**

```
1) Make Dashboard controller with 'index' action
2) Make Dashboard model and specify: var $useTable = false;
3) Set Route to use your Dashboard controller for homepage (or any other page: 
  `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index'));`
4) Use $this->loadModel('Whatever'); to gain access to that model's methods
```